# Как загрузить своё iOS-приложение в itunesconnect.apple.com если у тебя имеется только Windows PC?

Tags: xcode, macos, apple, appstore, loader

Готовлю своё **PhoneGap-приложение** к публикации в **AppStore**.

Осталось только загрузить **ipa-файл** приложения на **itunesconnect.apple.com**.

Есть два варианта: **Xcode** или **Application Loader** и оба требуют наличие **Mac'а**, а у меня только **Windows PC**- как быть?

Comment: поставить хакинтош

Comment: @Denis а чего не ответ?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko перенёс в ответ!

Answer (score 3):

В таких случаях рекомендуется поставить Хакинтош на виртуальную машину.

Например, вот [одна из сотен статей](https://www.iphones.ru/iNotes/os-x-pc-virtual-machine-guide), которая расскажет, как это сделать. При установке может придётся немного пошаманить, но зато у вас не возникнет больше проблем, связанных с отсутствием мака.

Comment: Все кидаются статьями, под каждой статьей куча комментариев людей у которых система не заработала. Здесь много тонкостей и деталей, всё наверное зависит от конфигурации PC-железа.  У меня к примеру старый ноут на двухядерном Пентиуме, с 2Гб оперативы и 100% без поддержки аппаратной виртуализации. Потому стоит ли тратить время на все эти танцы с бубном не известно..

Comment: @Enshtein так это надо было сразу указывать в вопросе